# gathering item lists from eBay

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to figure out a way for somehow fetching the all the items from a given category. I don't even know if it is legal to do so. But im curious :) I need to gather the items then i will put them in my own database by using C#.net or java, it doesn't matter.

Is there any API or service for doing so?

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ebay has a developer network. And an API to find things You can view the information here:
https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/finding-api

The other option is to write a scraper.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with tester123's answer.

> The other option is to write a scraper.

That violates eBay's user agreement (http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/user-agreement.html) (ctrl+f "scrape").

But the greater matter at hand is the problem with the API. See this question: [Get all item's in a category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615605/)

As I answered there, the call limit is 100 items per page MAX, 100 pages into any search MAX. The first limit is obvious, the second means that you can't ever reach page 101 of the results even if you intend to start there. You are limit to the first 10,000 results of the search you conduct, so if there are greater than that many items in a category (and for popular categories there will be), then it cannot be done.

I hope you find this more helpful, even if it may be disappointing. It is true, though, that scraping would be the only way to surpass these limitations (because you set you're own ;), although it would be more difficult...).